# What is the difference here?

Tags: python

I am learning python and here is a small code that instructions want me to write.

> First, def a function called cube that takes an argument called
>   number. Don't forget the parentheses and the colon! Make that function
>   return the cube of that number (i.e. that number multiplied by itself
>   and multiplied by itself once again). Define a second function called
>   by_three that takes an argument called number.

if that number is divisible by 3, by_three should call cube(number) and return its result. Otherwise, by_three should return False.

What I did first was;

```
def cube(number): 
    return number ** 3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        cube(number)
        return number
    else:
        return False
```

but apparently in this, by_three(number) returns number itself. so to my understandings, the cube(Number) and return number doesnt work by line order?

this works:

```
def cube(number): 
    return number ** 3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False
```

I know why this works, but I dont get why the other one doesnt.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please indent your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't assign the return of the `cube()` function to a variable. So `cube(number)` returns a number, then gets forgotten and you just return number which was originally passed into `by_three()`. If in your first one you did `number = cube(number)` it would reassign the cubed number to the number variable and it would work.

**EDIT for additional info**

A simple way to think about it is when passing immutable data types such as integers, floats or strings, after a function evaluates and returns data, that data essentially replaces your function call. So you can imagine:

```
def cube(number): 
    return number ** 3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        9
        return number
    else:
        return False
```

This helps illustrate why nothing happens since 9 just on it's own has no relationship to the VARIABLE `number`. Granted this isn't valid python code, but you can just imagine the process of what's happening behind the scenes here. So as I stated by reassigning the number, it would be doing this behind the scenes and reassigning `number` with the `cube()` returned value of 9:

```
def cube(number): 
    return number ** 3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        number = 9
        return number
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Haha, finally! I always post an answer and by the time I click post it's already answered.

Comment: _"Granted this isn't valid python code"_ - All of the code you posted is completely valid Python. It's perfectly legal to put an expression in the body of a control structure.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Christian Dean. I forgot that it is technically valid Python code. I should have probably said that that line with the number 9 alone is 'useless' code without doing something with it. But hopefully the explanation helps make sense of the evaluation process for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

**What went wrong:**

This is because you didn't store the result of `cube(number)` in any variable. and when the program proceeds to the next line `return number` it returns the number.

**Example:**

```
def example(number):
  number + 5
  return number

print(example(7))
```

the result is: 7

since I didn't do anything to store my result of `number + 5` when I call `example(5)` I get the `number` itself back

**but now consider:**

```
def example(number):
  number = number + 5
  return number

print(example(7))
```

the result is: 12

This is because I updated `number` with the result of `number + 5`.

I hope this helps you get a better understanding of what was wrong with your code. Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find this answer of any other helpful and solves your problem please mark it as the solution. That way it will help the community and fellow programmers who run into the same question as you in the future. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Python passes pass variables by assignment. That means when you pass an argument to a function, the parameter that corresponds to the argument is assigned a reference to the argument object.

In your code, when you pass `number` to the `cube()` function, the `number` parameter of `cube()` is assigned a reference to that object. However, you never do anything with that reference. You simply return a new object. This `number` is never changed. But even if you did attempt to change `number` inside of `cube()`, that would fail as well because Python would treat the assignment as a new declaration of a variable named `number` inside of `cube()`.

This behavior can be demonstrated with a simple example:

```
>>> def func(n):
    print(id(n))
    print(id(n ** 3))
    n = 2
    print(id(n))


>>> def func2(n):
    print(id(n))
    func(n)


>>> func2(3)
1612339504
1612339504
1612339888
1612339488
>>>
```

The `id()` function returns a unique number for each object created in your program. As you can see above, the `3` passed into `func2()`is the same object passed into `func()`. However, when we use `n` in the expression `n ** 3`, a new object is created. The same thing applies to the assignment `n = 2`. When we do that, Python treats that as a variable declaration, and a new variable local to `func()` is created with a reference to the new object `2`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not storing the result of cube anywhere and you are just returning the number itself.

I think what confused you is, inside `cube()` function you are returning `number`. Now you think, it is the same `number` variable inside the other function. But it is not. You need to reassign the value to some variable so as to use it.

```
...
cube_num = cube(number)
return cube_num
```

Now this would work. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The first one doesn't work because variables in functions are not global. What does this mean? Look at the following code:

```
def add(number):
    return number + 3

add(number)
print(number)
```

If you try this code, you will get `NameError: name 'number' is not defined`. This is because the variable `number` is a LOCAL variable. It stays inside the function, having fun, and then it dies after the function ends. This also means that if you switch `by_three(number)` with `by_three(number2)`...

```
def cube(number):
    return number ** 3

def by_three(number2):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        cube(number2)
        return number
    else:
        return False
```

It will show the error `name 'number' is not defined.`. When you use number instead, you are getting the output of the number you put in `by_three(number)`, not `cube(number)`. Thus, `return cube(number)` works because the number in `cube(number)` is different from the number in `by_three(number)`.

---

### Possible Approaches

If you still want to do a similar process like this, you can make a variable equal to the function `cube(number)`. Example:

```
if number2 % 3 == 0:
    cubedNumber = cube(number2)
    return cubedNumber
else
    return False
```

Now `by_three(3)` shows 27 instead.

---

### Assigning a Global Variable

A global variable is default when outside a function; as a local variable if otherwise. To make a variable global, simply put `global variable_name`. However, you can't just do `global variable = "something"`; you must make it a global variable before assigning it. Anyways, in this scenario, it's not recommended, and I don't even bother putting a couple lines of code just to make the function work, because it will be global for the rest of the code.